# How to make this code DRY?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I'm writing RESTful service with C#/wcf and need to put filters on GET. Like how many records to return, maybe if I want to filter by something, etc. Consider this code:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "/devices/{DeviceId}/positions")]
        public List<GPSPosition> GetDevicePositions(string deviceId)
        {
            //Lookup device:
            using (var context = new MobileModelContext(ContextManager.AccountGKey.Value))
            {
                var d = context.Devices.Where(aa => aa.DeviceId == deviceId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (d == null)
                {
                    outgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    outgoingResponse.StatusDescription = "Device not found";
                    return null;
                }

                var query = from p in context.Positions
                            where p.DeviceKey.Equals(d.DeviceKey)
                            select new GPSPosition
                            {
                                PositionGKey = p.PositionGKey,
                                Latitude = p.Latitude,
                                Longitude = p.Longitude,
                                Speed = p.Speed,
                                Accuracy = p.Accuracy,
                                Altitude = p.Altitude,
                                GPSTime = p.GPSTime,
                                DeviceTime = p.DeviceTime
                            };

                return query.ToList();
            }
        }

        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/devices/{DeviceId}/positions?RecordCount={RecordCount}")]
        public List<GPSPosition> GetDevicePositions2(string deviceId, int recordCount)
        {
            //Lookup device:
            using (var context = new MobileModelContext(ContextManager.AccountGKey.Value))
            {
                var d = context.Devices.Where(aa => aa.DeviceId == deviceId).FirstOrDefault();
                if (d == null)
                {
                    outgoingResponse.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                    outgoingResponse.StatusDescription = "Device not found";
                    return null;
                }

                var query = from p in context.Positions
                            where p.DeviceKey.Equals(d.DeviceKey)
                            select new GPSPosition
                            {
                                PositionGKey = p.PositionGKey,
                                Latitude = p.Latitude,
                                Longitude = p.Longitude,
                                Speed = p.Speed,
                                Accuracy = p.Accuracy,
                                Altitude = p.Altitude,
                                GPSTime = p.GPSTime,
                                DeviceTime = p.DeviceTime
                            };

                return query.Take(recordCount).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Lot of repetition. I can move code into other function but still, I have 2 templates, I have 2 functions. Is there any way to make 1 template for /positions/ that will cover all possible "?" scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**QA Hint**: `context.Devices.Where(aa => aa.DeviceId == deviceId).FirstOrDefault();` can be shorten to `context.Devices.Find(deviceId);`

**QA Hint**: `from p in context.Positions ...` you may want to create a view on your table and instead of `... select new GPSPosition { ... }` you would simply write regular `context.PositionViews.Where(x => x.DeviceKey == d.DeviceKey).ToList();`

**QA Hint**: You may want to use `.AsNoTracking()` to optimize performance.

**QA Hint**: You may want to use optional parameters in your method declarations. For example:

```
public List<GPSPosition> GetDevicePositions(string deviceId, int limit = 20)
{
// you code here
}
```

Or if WCF doesn't support it *just yet*. Here is a work-around:

> You can get the desired effect by
>   omitting the Query string from the
>   UriTemplate on your WebGet or
>   WebInvoke attribute, and using
>   WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.UriTemplateMatch.QueryParameters
>   from within your handlers to inspect,
>   set defaults, etc. on the query
>   parameters.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=451296&wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: #1: Not sure how this will work since I need to specify which column I'm searching, correct?

#2: Won't work. GPSPosition is POCO class specifically created for REST+JSON. If I take entity-generated class then it looks really bad when it's JSON. This is why I have it like this in first place.

#3 can I use optional paramteres with WCF templates?!

Comment: #1: Find(..) searches by Key column (I assume DeviceId is a key column), #2 Works perfectly with POCO classes, you can apply mapping there as needed

Comment: No, deviceId is not a key column. It is unique index but primary key is IDENTITY so it's not working like this. #2. Is that really so expensive? In reality - there going to be handful of records at most.

Comment: #1. ok, you may shorten you code by inserting where clause in `FirstOrDefault()` method then: `context.Devices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeviceId == deviceId)`

Comment: Great! That last edit you made seems to be exactly what I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

> Take   enumerates source and
>   yields elements until count elements
>   have been yielded or source contains
>   no more elements.

Since [`Take(n)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) returns *at a maximum* n items, but less if there are less available you can rewrite:

```
  public List<GPSPosition> GetDevicePositions(string deviceId)
  {
    return GetDevicePositions2(deviceId, int.MaxValue)
  }
```

which will then return all items.

Comment: Thanks! This is kind of what I though, but I wonder if there is "optional" paramters I can use with templates?